# tf.contrib.learn Estimator avoid writing events.out.tfevents.* file

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

I am training a model using `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`. Because my `model_dir` is a location in the Google cloud storage, uploading the model takes a while. The problem is that intermediate results are saved in a `events.out.tfevents` file.
Is it possible to write this file only at the end of fitting or avoid writing to this file? Currently, all time is spent uploading this file instead of actually fitting the model. If this would be only at the beginning and the end of the fitting, this wouldn't be a problem.

```
estimator_full_model = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
        model_fn=network_train.build_model_fn(),
        params={'train_op': 'full_model',
                'learning_rate': 0.01,
                'mask_train': None},
        model_dir='data',
        feature_engineering_fn=train_feature_engineering_fn,
        config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=None,
                                          save_checkpoints_steps=100000,
                                          log_device_placement=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not interface to write events file at the end of training as far as I know, but you can reduce the frequency of writing events file by increase `save_summary_steps` in `config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig` into a acceptable frequency.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have added  save_summary_steps= 2000 in the RunConfig. But the events file is still being written more often then every 2000 steps.

INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.545086, step = 201 (25.491 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.549882, step = 301 (97.587 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.52498, step = 401 (25.509 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.416154, step = 501 (102.545 sec)

There can be seen in the longer execution time that the file is being written every 200 steps, which is weird as the default 'save_summary_steps' is 100.

Comment: Can I see more detail of your code ? Is there any other place take effect of tf.summary.FileWriter ?

Comment: Did you add hooks when `estimator_full_model.train()` , or called `estimator_full_model .evaluate()` ?

Comment: I'm just creating the same estimator as in my first post with the `save_summary_steps` argument added and calling `estimator_full_model.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=8000)`. There are no monitors added and tf.summary is not being used.

Comment: what's your version of tf?

Comment: tensorflow==1.3.0rc2